# mvc3 ajax.actionlink coding for model failure

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I'm using an `ajax actionlink` to allow the user to delete a record in the `model (database table)`.
User `clicks` on `delete link`,
 `JQuery dialog` opens to ask for confirmation.  
User confirms they want to delete, actionlink calls relevant method on controller.
Method tries to delete relevant record in database but fails, for example, database is down for some reason.
Because I'm not updating an element on the page (I suspect onSuccess will fire?), how can I convey that the record has not been deleted?
So really I'm asking how to pass a return value from the method to the Ajax ActionLink, or force the `onFailure` to fire. 
I suspect I can have a hidden field and update that using `UpdateTargetId`, and then call a function `onSuccess` to check the value - but Is this the best way or will this even work?

Comment: Sounds like this might be easier to do in pure jQuery than using the MS Ajax tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OnSuccess and OnFailure properties in AjaxOptions:

```
<p>
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click Me", "About", new AjaxOptions { OnFailure = "OnFailureFunc", OnSuccess = "OnSuccessFunc" })
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnFailureFunc() {
        alert("Error");
    }
    function OnSuccessFunc() {
        alert("Success");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not encouraging the use of `Ajax.ActionLink` (because I like using jQuery.ajax better) but to elaborate on this response a bit, the OnFailure *will* be called when the server responds anywhere outside the 200 range: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onfailure.aspx

Comment: @David So, because I don't want to update the page, it will always return success - So looks like JQuery ajax is the way forward, otherwise I have to go down the UpdateTagetId and check the value in my hidden field route?

Comment: If your ajax call throws an error while code executes on the server, the response should not be 200. The whole point of the `AjaxOptions.OnFailure` property is to allow a client function to handle errors. It seems strange to respond with 200 if the server *actually* threw an error--such as the database down, etc.